# Is there an option to hide my character's helmet?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'd really like to hide my helmet. I haven't found any in-game options, but maybe I missed it. Is there an option somewhere, or an INI file I can edit, to be able to do this?

Comment: This has never been a feature of a TES game, so it's unlikely TES5 can do it. Do you want it just for visuals in 3rd-person, for taking screenshots of your character, or some other reason? Would being able to quickly take it off and put it back on be helpful?

Comment: It seemed strange that you can customize appearence of your character and then hide it with helmet

Comment: Not everyone will choose to wear a helmet or a hood. When I made mages in Oblivion, they usually went bare-headed.

Comment: I also would very much like to do this. The armor trees punish you for not wearing a full set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no option to hide helmets.

If you really want that badly, I'd wait for the modding community. They will surely come up with something.

Answer (score 5):

What I do is that I put my helmet in my favorites. Then, I can put it on or remove it quickly, whenever I want to see my character face. Otherwise, I don't think there is an automated way.

Answer (score 5):

There is a mod for this now: [No Helmet Mod](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=562). Make sure to read the description and contact the author if the helmet you want hasn't been changed by the mod.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you have the vampire abilties then your guild hood will not appear but you will also appear balding. Which is annoying.